# Unicorn Worker Pool going idle and slowing down a lot after a period of time

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm running [Teambox](http://teambox.com) community edition on an Ubuntu Server machine, with 600Mhz and 358MB of RAM. I know it's not much and that's probably the cause of all the trouble I'm having, but maybe someone knows another solution.

The thing is, I'm running Unicorn as a Rails server, using 2 workers (more would just clog up the ram completely), and they work perfectly when they're up and running. But after about 15-30 minutes (I think), the workers' RAM usage drops a lot, and if I try to reach my Teambox installation, it takes forever to load, and most of the time the request will timeout showing me an ugly "Proxy Failed" screen.

I'm connecting to the unicorn workers using an Apache Proxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server with so little CPU and memory, perhaps it would be better to try using nginx?

To be honest, if you are only using the system internally, there would be no reason not to just access Unicorn directly (and change it to run on port 80).